# split a view horizontally in two part in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi i'm new in REACT NATIVE, i have a  in my react native app, with style of a card like the code below. first i want to split it into two horizontally parts with the ratio of( 3 for upper part and 2 for lower part). And second i want to write  on each part.
I

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
return(
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={styles.results}>
          <Text style={styles.texty}>numbers</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.calculations}>
          <Text>numbers</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      );
      };
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      card: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "80%",
    height: 100,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    elevation: 5, 
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 100,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginTop: 80,
    margin: 42,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  texty: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  calculations: {
    fontSize: 34,
  },
  results: {
    flex: 6,
    paddingTop: 25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    borderBottomWidth: 0.3,
    borderBottomColor: "grey",
      });
```

brought my code down there

Answer (score 1):

Please use flex property to achieve this like:

```
card: { flex: 1 }
results: { flex: .6, flexWrap:'wrap'}
calculations: {flex:.4, flexWrap:'wrap'}
```

P.S:

```
You can add other styles as you like but don't use height property.
```